# (HTML) how to bold navigation bar text?

Tags: html, css, navigation

How do I bold the text in the navigation bar (Home, portfolio, Contact, About Me, etc) when the visitor is on that page?

For example, if the visitor is on my "Portfolio" page, I want that text to be bold on my navigation bar while the others stay normal. Similarly, if the visitor goes to "Contact" page, I want the text "Contact" to be bold and everything else to stay normal.

2nd question: is this easier to do in HTML? Or is this something I should do in css?

Comment: show what have you done so far, your efforts

Answer (score 5):

Add a active class to the HTML

### HTML:

```
<ul id="navigation">
  <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="portfolio.html" class="active">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="about.html">About Me</a></li>
</ul>
```

### CSS:

```
ul#navigation .active {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

So on `home.html` the active class will be on the Home link. For the `contact.html` will be on the Contact link and so on...

Answer (score 0):

If you are serving up static web pages(which seems to be the case in this situation),then just explicitly specify a bold property to whichever HTML element you want to make bold in the particular HTML file and so on like Sarcasm has done in the above answer.
But if you are dynamically generating webpages then make different templates and then specify the properties tailored for the particular template.(I assume that ou know how to use id and class in HTML)